# An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm trying to figure how to add an attribute to root node. I have following xslt to transform two different types of xml files. 1st xml file is transformed fine I have the problem when its second xml file my xslt throws error "An item of type 'Attribute' cannot be constructed within a node of type 'Root" how do i fix this in xslt

XSLT File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <!--Check whether lossformsVersion exists If not write-->
  <xsl:template match="Inspection[not(@lossFormsVersion)]">
    <xsl:attribute name="lossFormsVersion">07-25-2013-1-54</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Replace the lossformsVersion with this templates version-->
  <xsl:template match="Inspection/@lossFormsVersion">
    <xsl:attribute name="lossFormsVersion">07-25-2013-1-54</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <!--Copy the rest of the document as it is-->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

### 1st XML FILE (Before Transformation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Inspection lossFormsVersion="07-25-2013-1-52">
.
.
.
</Inspection>
```

### 1st XML FILE (After Transformation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Inspection lossFormsVersion="07-25-2013-1-54">
.
.
.
</Inspection>
```

### 2nd XML FILE (Before Transformation)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Inspection>
.
.
.
</Inspection>
```

2nd XML File After transformation should look exactly like 1st transformed XML file. Thanks in advance

Comment: In your first template you matched the root node but didn't write out an element node. You attempted to output a "naked" attribute node not attached to an element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<xsl:template match="Inspection[not(@lossFormsVersion)]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="lossFormsVersion">07-25-2013-1-54</xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

For 2nd xml, your template matches the element where you write the attribute to output.
xsl:copy copies the Ïnspection node and the attribute writes to that.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking that the two match patterns

```
match = "Inspection [not(@lossFormsVersion)]"
```

and

```
match = "Inspection / @lossFormsVersion"
```

are parallel; if they were parallel, then the behavior you observe would indeed be surprising.

But they are not parallel, and the sooner you grasp how and why, the sooner you'll be comfortable with XPath and XPath-based languages.  The first pattern matches *elements* whose element type name is `Inspection`, and which do not have a `lossFormsVersion` attribute.  The second pattern matches *attributes* named `lossFormsVersion` located on `Inspection` attributes.

Once you're clear on that, the logic of the answer offered by gp should be clear.